# How to add count (n) / summary statistics as a label to ggplot2 boxplots?

Tags: ggplot2, count, sample-size

I am new to R and trying to add count labels to my boxplots, so the sample size per boxplot shows in the graph.

This is my code:

```
  bp_east_EC <-total %>% filter(year %in% c(1977, 2020, 2021, 1992),
                                 sampletype == "groundwater",
                                 East == 1,
                                 #EB == 1,
                                 #N59 == 1,
                                 variable %in% c("EC_uS")) %>%

ggplot(.,aes(x = as.character(year), y = value, colour = as.factor(year))) +
theme_ipsum() +
ggtitle("Groundwater EC, eastern Curacao") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14)) +
theme(legend.position = "none") +
labs(x="", y="uS/cm") +
geom_jitter(color="grey", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2) #shows mean
```

I have googled a lot and tried different things (with annotate, with return functions, mtext, etc), but it keeps giving different errors. I think I am such a beginner I cannot figure out how to integrate such suggestions into my own code.

Does anybody have an idea what the best way would be for me to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new variable that contained your sample sizes per group and plot that number with `geom_label`. I've generated an example of how to add count/sample sizes to a boxplot using the `iris` dataset since your example isn't fully reproducible.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

# boxplot with no label
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# boxplot with label
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_label(aes(label= count , y = mean + 0.75), # <- change this to move label up and down
            size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.35, aes(color = Species))  +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 23, size = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this plot the label for every observation?